# Good Python based ETL

Tags: python

I'm looking for a Python (scripting) based ETL (Extract - Transform - Load ) package. There seems to be a few options available and I'm looking for something fairly stable and which can support the tasks:

- Open attachments from email on Exchange server.
- Read csv files
- Read xls and xlsx files
- Read json files
- Read xml files
- read through ftp connection, with authentication
- read through web service, with authentication
- write to postgresql
- Scheduled to run daily on windows server

I've been looking at options as :

- https://www.bonobo-project.org/
- https://petl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
- https://pandas.pydata.org/index.html

Any thoughts on which will do the job best ?

Looking forward to your advice!

Christian